# It's possible to obtain a bean without import on an java interface?

Tags: java, spring, maven, maven-profiles

Can you tell me if it's possible to make this on my application?

I have maven profiles, with 2 configurations of beans:

applicationContext-service.xml (1):

and applicationContext-service.xml (2):

This with profile generate the correct target xml and the inyection too with one single package.

The problem is:

The facade have one method: getServiceA() that return "the spring bean" but, in the definition and implementation is necesary to add:

import service.postgres.ServiceA; or
import service.oracle.ServiceA;

It's possible to make the interface and implementation of this without import dependency to return the correct bean?

ServiceA is an implementation and it's not possible to create an interface ServiceA for facadeService, because it have statics methods.

Thanks!

Comment: applicationContext-service.xml(1):                                                  
  <bean id="ServiceFacade" class="service.facade.ServiceFacadeImpl"
            p:ServiceA-ref="serviceA" />
            
<bean id="serviceA" class="service.postgres.ServiceA"/>   and applicationContext-service.xml(2) is simmilar but class="service.oracle.ServiceA"

Comment: If your problem is with the name of the classes being same, you can do `class My class implements service.oracle.ServiceA {}` without importing.